# Running commands on user login?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tty, display, window

First before anything I have installed a Ubuntu 16.10

After I installed it I have a tty1 open. I have installed Xorg and xfwm4 (X Window Manager)

If I do following:

- tty1: login
- type: startx
- tty2: login
- type: export DISPLAY=:0
- type: chromium-browser
- tty1: (Chromium Browser will be there and
  open)

How can I automate such a thing without doing it manually every time? It should happen after login, but only if user login is happened in TTY1. I don't want reserve the other TTYs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always start chromium? If yes, you need a running X-Server. So, you may just want to use the desktop environment to auto start chromium. For XFCE (You use XFCE, right?) see:

https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/autostart-in-xfce-4.3-wie/

Comment: The actual problem is that, because I don't want to use xfce. I want use (super extremely lightweight) way to open browser. Kiosk mode doesn't show the Window bars. I noticed that the .bash_profile executes on login too, but running a 'startx' doesn't allow me to run other commands (from same) shell. So basically this won't work: "startx && chromium-browser" while running startx the console output will stop with executing rest of commands.

Comment: Ah. I see your point. May you try it with xinit? See here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit

Comment: On .xinitrc there's "exec xfwm4", but I cannot make it work to start Window Manager and then start Chromium. It starts only the Window Manager. I think that the startx output will break the executing the rest of commands.

Comment: Did you try to add chromium to xinitrc?

Comment: Actually yes, but I am not sure did I format it properly. I tried "exec xfwm4 && chromium-browser" after that I also tried "exec xfwm4" and under that a line "exec chromium-browser"

Comment: Did you try with just `exec chromium-browser` without exec xfwm4?

Comment: Once, but it cannot run on tty1. That is why I need X Window Manager (xfwm4) that need to be running first of course.

Comment: Actually the problem is that if I run multiple commands on .bash_profile the other commands doesn't execute until "startx" (X Window Manager) is terminated, because output will pause executing the commands. I need to run them line by line as "standalone"

Comment: You confuse me. Did you try this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit#Starting_applications_without_a_window_manager? You should be able to start chromium-browser without xfwm4. Xinit is startet by startx which stats X (obviously).

Comment: Okay, let me explain. I can start the browser if I modify .xinitrc to "exec chromium-browser", but it looks terrible, because there's no X Window Manager. No controls to close, resize, leaves a black panel top of the page (margin). http://prntscr.com/ddmsvj so I want... >>

Comment: ... basically I want to run such a command: startx & export DISPLAY=:0 && chromium-browser (but) now we get to this point. When the startx starts running on tty1 the rest of commands cannot be executed due the output/running startx on tty1. So in example "gnome-terminal -e myCommands" should work, but now we meet another problem in this point, because gnome-terminal is virtual terminal and meant to be ran on display. So I basically I want these commands to be ran as their own so I can execute startx and then execute rest of commands.

Comment: Ah. I see. In my opinion you solution in the last comment should work. But, you just need one & to send process to the background. And, may be you need to `sleep 5` to wait after startx. May chromium tries to start, but x ist not ready yet. `startx & sleep 5; export DISPLAY=:0; chromium-browser`.

Comment: Be careful to NOT put a & after sleep. Because you want to wait for sleep. If you put a & it wont wait... Also you want to wait for export. So, no & after export...

Comment: This is absolutely what I tried, but when startx starts and you submit a sleep command there it will pause execution of startx for 5 seconds. It doesn't make sense anyways if I'm correct the startx is running on tty1 and it tries to execute commands in same console where startx writes it's output on background.

Comment: Wait. You tried this? Why didn't you tell me this EXACTLY?!? I stop my help here. Write all your tries in you post. Describe what you did exactly. Describe, why you do all this. Then I help you again.

Comment: That's your choice. I was trying 100 different things while I wait answers. Why should I edit the post between 5 seconds, because of failed attempts. Since if I find working solution I'd rather release the answer for everyone here. I give you a one more information and few words.

Comment: Well the couple words. Your comments gives me a good information and I'm thankful about them, but seems that you don't understand the part if I run startx on tty1 the tty1 is reserved... It cannot be used to execute commands, because it's printed full of output text. You provided me a command "startx & sleep 5; ..." Did you read the comment above my friend?

Comment: Look. I try to help you, but every time I give some help, I get some more information. It's just not very thankful to help like this...

Comment: Because I'm trying different solutions all the time and if I update all attempts there, there will be 1000 lines more. I think I gotta try to make two shell scripts and another contains a sleep 5 on start. But even if it is in shell script it executes the script in same console where script is ran.

Comment: Are you online? chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49372/discussion-between-tobias-and-weird-e

Comment: Back to your problem. Well, the part with "run startx on tty1 the tty1 is reserved" is just not true, if you use startx &. It is true, you get output. But this does not mean, you cant start something from tty1. This is why I proposed startx & sleep 5; export DISPLAY=:0; chromium-browser. Did you try this? And, sleep here does not sleep startx. I am quite sure... Do you understand the &?